# Dual Bra of the ground state of interacting theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum

I'm currently reading Peskin's "An introduction to Quantum Field Theory", but I'm stuck on page 87; I don't understand why he gets such a Bra for the vaccum state of the interacting theory, say $\langle \Omega |$:
$$\langle \Omega | = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)} \langle 0 | U(t,t_0)\left(e^{-iE_0(t-t_0)}\langle 0|\Omega\rangle \right)^{-1} $$
If i start from the previous definition of the Ket:
$$|\Omega\rangle = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{-iE_0(t+t_0)}\langle \Omega|0\rangle \right)^{-1}U(t_0,-t)|0\rangle  $$
Just applying the rules for the adjoint (or dual), I end up with the following:
$$\langle \Omega | = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)} \langle 0 | U(-t,t_0)\left(e^{iE_0(t+t_0)}\langle 0|\Omega\rangle \right)^{-1} $$
Where I've used the property $U^\dagger(t,t')=U(t',t)$.

From here, the author deduces the rest of the expressions from his previous result, but I cannot understand why he gets that.

Comment: be careful with the imaginary term in limit

Comment: what do you mean, which term do you refer to? are you talking about $t\rightarrow \infty(1-i\epsilon)$? or about the exponential term.

Comment: former term $t\to\infty(1-i\epsilon)$

Comment: Okay, but I could redefine things in a different way. If I just transform temporal parameter as $ t\rightarrow t(1-i\epsilon)$ and then take the real limit $t\rightarrow \infty$, Things are right up to the Ket:
$$|\Omega\rangle = \left(e^{-iE_0(t+t_0)}\langle \Omega|0\rangle \right)^{-1}U(t_0,-t)|0\rangle
$$
which must be valid for $t\gg 1$. But taking the dual of this expression I obtain 
$$\langle \Omega | =  \langle 0 | U(-t,t_0)\left(e^{iE_0(t+t_0)}\langle 0|\Omega\rangle \right)^{-1}\qquad (t\gg 1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Start from
$$
\langle 0|e^{-iHT} = \sum_n \langle 0|e^{-iHT} |n\rangle \langle n|= \sum_n \langle 0|e^{-iE_nT} |n\rangle \langle n|
$$
from which
$$
\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty(1-i\varepsilon)}\langle 0|e^{-iHT}= e^{-iE_\Omega T} \langle 0 |\Omega \rangle \langle \Omega|
$$
and
\begin{align}
\langle \Omega| =&\, \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty(1-i\varepsilon)}\left( e^{-iE_\Omega T} \langle 0 |\Omega \rangle \right)^{-1}\langle 0|e^{-iHT}\\
=&\, \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty(1-i\varepsilon)}\left( e^{-iE_\Omega (T-t_0)} \langle 0 |\Omega \rangle \right)^{-1}\langle 0|e^{-iH(T-t_0)} \\
=&\, \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty(1-i\varepsilon)}\left( e^{-iE_\Omega (T-t_0)} \langle 0 |\Omega \rangle \right)^{-1}\langle 0|e^{iH_0(T-t_0)}e^{-iH(T-t_0)}\\
=&\, \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty(1-i\varepsilon)}\left( e^{-iE_\Omega (T-t_0)} \langle 0 |\Omega \rangle \right)^{-1}\langle 0|U(T,t_0)
\end{align}

Comment: That's right, but how could you derive the same final expression by taking the dual of ket?:
$$|\Omega\rangle = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{-iE_0(t+t_0)}\langle \Omega|0\rangle \right)^{-1}U(t_0,-t)|0\rangle$$
Shouldn't you get the same?

Comment: As mentioned by @physshyp you also need to change the limit when you want to do it that way.

Comment: Directly conjugation simply won't work. At least not directly. Because it would be equivalent to expanding $\langle 0|e^{iHt}=\sum_n \langle 0|e^{iHt}|n\rangle\langle n|$ and sending $T$ to $\infty(1+i\epsilon)$; which is the same as expanding $\langle 0|e^{-iHt}=\sum_n \langle 0|e^{-iHt}|n\rangle\langle n|$ and sending $T$ to $\infty(-1-i\epsilon)$. This will give a different expression. As the answer suggested, you need to send $T$ to $\infty(1-i\epsilon)$ in $\langle 0|e^{-iHt}=\sum_n \langle 0|e^{-iHt}|n\rangle\langle n|$  to get Peskin and Schroeder's equation.